# Most efficient way to getting external local JSON REST API data from local service into a PHP application

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I have a XYZ service that I run locally that provides me the ability to do REST API calls to fetch JSON data from it. I've been doing the following to get the data into my PHP site:

[image]

As you can see I use ob_get_contents(), after I run my curl_exec() functions to communicate with the local service.

Is there a better way than using CURL to access this local REST API service? Or should I just use get_file_contents()?

Comment: As per [ask], please do not upload pictures of code

Comment: Anyway basically you are asking for alternatives to cURL in php...pretty sure you could google that. file_get_contents is one, although it's pretty simplistic. Or there are other http client libraries you can use such as Guzzle. Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: You don't need `ob_get_contents` here.

Comment: What are you trying to improve and why?

Comment: @Evert the content on the page loads one line at a time, due to my code fetching external api data and feeding it back into another api to get another result to be used in another api call. ob_get_contents() lets you display it all at once vs line at a time as the page loads. I was just wondering if there is an alternative to this solution.

Comment: It's still not super clear *why* you want an alternative.

Comment: Agreed. What problem do you want to solve specifically with any alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's your problem with cURL. You have a working solution. I would not use `file_get_contents`, because you might want to add request headers and handle response headers such as authorization, content-type, cache, error, etc.